# Why do some docker files copy files instead of mount them as a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Can somebody explain to me why some Dockerfiles have steps to copy files rather than just mount a volume with the files on.

I have been looking at the setup for a Django project with Docker and the dockerfile has steps with copy commands in:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

In other Dockerfiles I have used (homeassistant) I have just mounted a directory as a volume and it's worked. What's going on here?

Can't I just keep the code and requirements in the same folder and mount them?

Just can't get my head around it

Edit:

For reference I'm looking at the [Docker site tutorial for Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) and it mounts the root dir as /code

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Why is that volume mounted to `/code` if we copy the files there anyway. Maybe that is what is throwing me off?

Comment: does the /code directory exist?

Comment: Yes it does. I've edited my question with more info if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Volumes are used to manage files stored by the Docker container. It allows the Docker container to write to that specific location on the file system. If the only thing you want is to execute a piece of code, it is better to just copy it over to the Docker container so that it does not have write access to the file-system of the host.

Edit:
I do not actually know why they specify the volume in the docker compose setup. The `build: .` specifies it should use the `Dockerfile` in the current directory, which already includes the copy statement. It seems a bit pointless. Might be a mistake in the tutorial.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. I didn't think of it that way! It's never going to be writing to the host at all. All static files that are uploaded to the web app will be on S3.

I'm guessing it does it in steps because then they can be cached and create a quicker build?

Comment: Yes exactly, it creates a layer with the needed libraries and a layer with the actual code

Comment: Ok thanks. I have updated my question with a bit more info around the mounting of volumes

Comment: Ok glad it seems pointless to you too! I'm assuming if I have my dockerfile and code in different directories I just need to update the paths accordingly, and I should be good to go! Going to go try it now! Thanks

Comment: yes exactly. Depending on where your docker-compose file resides, the paths need to be updated.